# How to chain these effects in jquery? Queue? Promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these two unconnected functions, there is at least no way to make a callback. I first want the list to slide up, THEN the other down. For making it work practically, at least, somehow, I added the `delay()`.

I cannot make a fsFiddle, since the code is too complex and all the `<a>` have an `href`in it, but you can see the working example here: http://liebdich.biz/.

What would do the job here and how: `queue`, `promise`?

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('ul').delay(500).slideDown(500);
    $('a').removeClass('bold');
    $(this).addClass('bold');

    if ($(this).is('ul ul a')) {
        return;
    } else {
        $('a').not(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp(500);
    }
 });
```

Sorry, but I cannot make a jsFiddle, since all the `<a>`in the navigation have an `href`.

Comment: Easy. do the slideDown in the complete callback of the slideUp, that way the slideDown doesn't begin until the slideUp is "complete". Just keep in mind that said complete callback will be triggered once for each "a" you select, so it may make more sense to use `.promise().done(fnhere)` rather than the complete callback so that it will only happen once.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried it with the callback, as mayabelle wrote, but that is not working due to the complexity of the site. See my edited question for the link. Could you please elaborate on the `.promise()` thing? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinB Could you elaborate on that `.promise()`thing, please?

Comment: @KevinB Can you explain, when jQuery "sees" the function in the callback? Does it know, that there is something to handle in the callback? Or does it just run the function and looks then for the content of the callback? And could you please elaborate on the term "complete callback"? Why does the `.promise()` make it only run "once"?

Comment: the callback is seen immediately, however it doesn't execute until the animation is done. when you pass the callback to the complete event of the animation, `.sliceUp(duration,completeCallback)`, the callback will be triggered for each selected element, therefore if you're sliding up 4 content panels, i'l happen 4 times. `.promise().done(completeCallback)` on the otherhand will only trigger it once because it's waiting for when all animations on currently selected elements are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be an appropriate place to use a promise object to avoid getting duplicated callbacks:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $('a').removeClass('bold');
    $this.addClass('bold');
    if ($this.is('ul ul a')) {
        $this.parent().find('ul').slideDown(500);
        return;
    } else {        
        $('a').not(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp(500).promise().done(function(){
            $this.parent().find('ul').slideDown(500);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I could not figure out why the `$this.parent().find('ul').slideDown(500);` twice, so I deleted the first, still works!! ;) I have to get into understanding what you did now. Have a good time!! :D

Comment: Hey Kevin, yesterday I fiddled around and got it working, but then I wanted to make an @ on my mac and as old windows user i closed the program. ;) Then I was totally disturbed and potentially had the working code still saved, but did not recognise it, arrrgh. I mean I had the `.promise()` function in an own line. Like so: `$this.parent().find('ul').promise().done(function(){slideDown(500)});`. Of course this code is not working, but can you help me with how the working code has to be? I cannot remember what I did!! I did something after reading the jQuery `.promise()` manual, but what?? ;)

Comment: Hohey Kevin, have you overlooked my funny question here?

Comment: i commented 3 hours ago on your question

Comment: Yes, no, I mean the question here above, with the `.promise()` on a separate line. :)

Comment: maybe, `$this.slideDown(500)`?

Comment: Then the two animations are firing simultaneously again?

Answer (score 1):

With Jquery, often you have with animation a callback function that is called once the animation is done.Here is the documentation of slideUp : http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

As you can see, if you use two parameters the second one is concerning a complete function which is called once the animation is done.

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    var _link = $(this);
    $('a').not(_link ).parent().find('ul').slideUp(500, function() {
        $(_link).parent().find('ul').delay(500).slideDown(500);
    });
});
```

I edited my code with some of your code. I still believe you will need to use the callback function for your problem.

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, there is no way for a callback here. See my edited question for the link! Thanks!

Comment: I think you can, you slide the first, once it's done, you write in the call back function the IF condition to check if it requires to slide the second level.

Comment: This is no second level, this is a whole different `ul`. ;) See my page link and click on services and then instruction. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').not(this).parent().find('ul').slideUp(500, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul').delay(500).slideDown(500);
});
```

Comment: Sorry I tried this, but that gives absolute chaos. As I said, there is no way for a callback. Do you know about queue or promise? See my edited question for the link of the working example!

Comment: you're losing `this`, you need to store it in a temp var.